# JWT token isn't validated even if it's correct using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile SDK for implementing Server code.

Code in OWIN startup is as below:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    new MobileAppConfiguration().ApplyTo(config);
    app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
    {
        SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
        ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
        ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
        TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
    });
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Token generation code:

```
Claim[] claims = new Claim[]
{
    new Claim("sub", "SampleSubject"),
    new Claim("Id", Convert.ToString(Users[0].user_id)),
    new Claim("name", Users[0].name),
    new Claim("surname", Users[0].surname),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user")
};
var token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"], TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
return token.RawData;
```

A sample JWT token is
`eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJHcnViZXJBUEkiLCJJZCI6IjMyODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkRhdmlkZSIsInN1cm5hbWUiOiJCb25ldHRhIiwicm9sZSI6InVzZXIiLCJ2ZXIiOiIzIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MjM1MzEvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6MjM1MzIvIiwiZXhwIjoxNTAyNDYyNDQzLCJuYmYiOjE0OTk4NzA0NDN9.b5VhWzvkaEumutPZpLzImcAy4NotXCSgUIqLltVUQWI`

The token is valid per below screenshot
[image: Decrypted JWT Token]

And for below code,

```
 [Authorize]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5 
    public string Get(int id)
    {

        try
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claims;
            AppServiceTokenHandler s = new AppServiceTokenHandler(new HttpConfiguration());
            s.TryValidateLoginToken(Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"], new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] }, new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] }, out claims);

            AppServiceTokenHandler.ValidateToken(Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return "value";
    }
```

'/Get' request fails with HTTP 401.
BUT For the same JWT token 'Get/5' returns HTTP 200 (validates token manually).

**The problem is, when I use `Authorize` attribute, api returns 401.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side.

[image]

[image]

**Access the protected Web API**

[image]

In summary, you could refer to the above screen shoot and check with your api endpoint. Additionally, you could refer to [AppServiceTokenHandler.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication/AppServiceTokenHandler.cs) and [HmacSigningCredentials.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/04d75cadc137cc478f98edfa1fa5b868e5548dfd/src/Common/HmacSigningCredentials.cs) for implementing your custom `TokenHandler` to troubleshoot this issue. Moreover, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Custom Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/custom/#custom-authentication)
.

Comment: Yep, this solved the problem. I have been passing token as Authorization header instead of "x-zumo-auth"